# Is "catch(console.error)" a valid way of catching Promise rejections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Let's say I have a Promise and catch the error like so:

```
fetch().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch(console.error);
```

Is this a valid code? I've seen people do this, but I don't understand how `catch(console.error)` works.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Notice how you can simplify to `fetch().then(console.log).catch(console.error);` or just `fetch().then(console.log, console.error);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you just want to log the error and otherwise ignore it, that works.

`.catch` expects you to pass it in a function, and if the promise rejects, that function will be called with the rejection value. Often you'll create a new function with custom logic and pass that in, but it's fine to pass in a function that already exists, such as `console.error`.

Answer (score 2):

yes it's all right.It's same as passing error object and then logging it in console.